# Save io.read() file reading result to a string

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

So I have some code:

```
  io.input(file)

  print(io.read())
  
  result = io.read()
  print(result)

  io.close(file)
```

and when I run this, I get

```
dasdasd
nil
```

where "dasdasd" is the content of the file. This signifies to me that the result of io.read() was not properly not saved to the string. Why is this the case? What am I missing?

Comment: `io.read()` reads next line of text from the file.  `dasdasd` is the first line of the file, `nil` means there is no second line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assuming `read()` goes back to the beginning each time.  This would require a `seek()` operation to be performed.   https://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/file%3Aseek

```
f  = io .input( 'filename.txt' )
print( f :read() )

f :seek('set')  --  set returns to the beginning
result  = f :read()
print( result )

f :close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Lua is not a [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) programming language, and `io.read()` is not a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). If you want to use the output from a call to it multiple times, you can't just call it multiple times. Save it to a variable and use that instead (like you did anyway immediately after your first call to it).